# MySQL tables join with python

Tags: python, mysql, join

i'm trying to fuse 2 MySQL tables in 1. Both tables have a column with the same values, so i would actually do a join. I'll show you the code i'm using to do that:

```
import MySQLdb
import _mysql

mobility = MySQLdb.connect(host="127.0.0.1", user="root", passwd="", db="Mobility")
mobility_cursor = mobility.cursor()

datasets = _mysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1',user='root',passwd='',db='datasets')
datasets.query("SELECT * FROM process_manager_Temp1")
proc_man_Temp1 = datasets.store_result()
proc_man_Temp1_dicts = proc_man_Temp1.fetch_row(maxrows=0, how=1)

for row in proc_man_Temp1_dicts:
    mobility_cursor.execute("UPDATE `process_manager_Temp` SET(`Resource`, `Format`) VALUES (%s,%s) WHERE `process`=%s ", (row['Resource'],row['format'],row['process'])
    mobility.commit()
```

It gives me an error on the last line. It says

> siimobility.commit()
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Antbody know what's wrong ? Oe may be there's a quicker way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not used your syntax before. I would try the following instead:

```
update process_manager_temp set resource = %s, format = %s where process = %s
```

on a side note, you probably don't need 2 different db connectors. just using MySQLdb is fine.

Comment: It is a different syntax but it usually works. Anyway your syntax is better readable. But that's not the problem. I still get the same error.

Comment: hmm. is that a mysql error, or python error? looks like you are missing a right paren in the 2nd to the last line.

Comment: Ok, i searched the error for 1 hour. Sorry about this question !! That was the problem, thanks. Anyway, are there any other methods to do this kind of join easier ?

Comment: I use sqlyog sja to generate a lot of automated reports. I think it also has a feature sync between dbs. you can give that a try.